# How do I turn off SWI-Prolog flags?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I'm not sure if flags is the appropriate term, but is there anyway to configure a swi-prolog program to not output true or false on the completion of a query, and instead simply print out another statement determined in the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a facility for customising this kind of behaviour, but it can get quite involved.  I have not played with it myself but looking at the manual and Prolog boot files might help you.

Prolog has a "top level", which is a bit of Prolog code that controls the Prolog command line and executes the goals entered on it.  With SWI-Prolog, you can specify an alternative top level:

```
pl -t my_quiet_prolog
```

If you define `my_quiet_prolog/0` in a file loaded on startup, e.g. in your `~/.plrc` file.

The default top level is called `prolog/0`.  The source for this, and other parts of the default Prolog environment can be found in `/usr/lib/pl-5.6.36/boot` (on my Cygwin system; possibly different for you).  Look at `toplevel.pl` for the default top level.  The messages 'Yes' and 'No' are also defined, in `messages.pl`.

You could try to override the messages, or simply copy the top level and modify it to suite you.