# Change the default output values in ​swi-prolog "true" and "false" for predicate evaluation

Tags: unit-testing, prolog, prolog-toplevel

When you execute anything in prolog you can see that the result of the evaluation comes out as:

> true

or

> false

I would like to change those values for personalized ones.

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490598/how-do-i-turn-off-swi-prolog-flags?noredirect=1&lq=1.), I saw that what I want is defined in the `messages.pl` file

where I found that they are defined as:

```
query_result(no) -->            % failure
    [ ansi(truth(false), 'false.', []) ],
    extra_line.
query_result(yes(true, [])) -->      % prompt_alternatives_on: groundness
    !,
    [ ansi(truth(true), 'true.', []) ],
    extra_line.
```

I'd like that instead of getting `false` or `true`, I could get `<ERROR::>` and `<PASSED::>` respectively for my unit tests.

## Additional info

I am doing the unit test to a file called `adition.pl` consisting solely of.

```
 my_add(A,B,Result):- number(A), number(B), is(Result,+(A,B)).
```

## Attempt

```
:-['C:/Users/RuslanLopez/Documents/Prolog/adittion.pl'].
%:-['C:/Program Files/swipl/boot/messages.pl'].
:- begin_tests(my_add).
:- include(adittion).
%:- use_module($messages).
%:- include(messages).
error:-write('<ERROR::>'),nl.
passed:-write('<PASSED::>'),nl.

:- dynamic(user:query_result/1).

user:query_result(no) -->            % failure
        [ ansi(truth(false),'<ERROR::>', []) ].

user:query_result(yes(true, [])) -->      % prompt_alternatives_on: groundness
        !,
        [ ansi(truth(true),'<PASSED::>' , []) ].




test(my_add):-
        my_add(1,2,Result),
        Result =:= 3.

test(my_add) :-
        my_add(1,2,Result),
        Result \= 4.

:- end_tests(my_add).
```

I understand that the more straightforward solution would be to go to the file and change the value directly there, but I really wish I could make the change at runtime to change that custom behavior only in my unit test and not for the entire system.

Comment: Couldn't you just [`call/1`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=call/1) the predicate to test and print accordingly based on success or failure? (Further, have you taken a look at [Prolog Unit Tests](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(%27packages/plunit.html%27))

Comment: @DavidTonhofer yes, however, it will print true or false in the console, that's what I want to silence without creating a repl.

Comment: The idea seems to be to modify the presentation to the user, who is working in the interpreter's REPL instead of a bespoke REPL. That requirement seems needlessly byzantine and "wedged"?

Comment: @DavidTonhofer I will not be calling it from the interpreters repl It's to be run inside a docker container. In this way it could be possible to add programming excercises to the codewars.com site

Comment: Would it be possible to start a Prolog process and perform query/response exchange using PLTP ("Prolog Transport Protocol") as described here: [Pengines: Web Logic Programming Made Easy](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(%27packages/pengines.html%27))

Comment: @DavidTonhofer but I don't want it to be interactive

Comment: Well, it should be like a JDBC or ODBC call to an SQL database, right? You don't want to change the prompt of the SQL database client program, you just want to issue a query from *your* program, get the rowset in return, and process it in whichever way you want. It's the same.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer it's actually like the SQL query terminator `;` was always added and I want to remove it, and I want to do it without modifying the library that adds such terminator.

Answer (score 3):

Don't. You want to change a very central part of a Prolog system, namely the toplevel (loop). But you will need this toplevel to interactively diagnose and debug your program. Any change to the toplevel will be visible in that context too. The toplevel is the result of many decades of Prolog use by various user groups. It contains much more than the response `true` and `false`. Just try `X = 1`, or even `X = s(s(X))`, or `dif(X,2)`.

`plunit` is a unit testing package availabe for SWI, SICStus and some further systems.  Use this instead, or roll our own, <s>based on</s> inspired by it.

Comment: So, are you saying that is not possible to redefine a system predicate on the fly? ( Context of my question https://github.com/Codewars/codewars-runner-cli/issues/159 )

Comment: Redefining system predicates is virtually never a good idea. (Exception maybe, if you want to correct an incorrect definition. But otherwise, never).

Comment: so it's possible?

Comment: Please read the manual. What you are asking in your original question is not possible that way. You have to change the source code to obtain that. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The toplevel is just a predicate `prolog/0` that is run when the Prolog interpreter is started. Command line options allow running another predicate or then you need to modified the existing is code, if you want a different toplevel by default.

I got an open source top-level in my Prolog system fully written in Prolog itself. It can also show solved constraints. Its open source here:

**Open Source: Module "session"**
[runtime/session.p](https://github.com/jburse/jekejeke-devel/blob/master/jekrun/headless/jekpro/reference/runtime/session.p)

The true and false values are internationalized through property files. So in German you see "Ja" and "Nein", and in English you see "Yes" and "No". Since internationalization API is not really standardized you find some custom built-in calls.

A properties file needs to be preloaded via this statement here:

```
:- sys_load_resource(runtime).
```

And a value for a key, depending on current language settings, is then retrieve via such a code sequence:

```
sys_show_assoc([], _) :-
   get_properties(runtime, P),
   get_property(P, 'query.yes', V),
   write(V).
```